AWS Quicksight cannot list Athena databases
When adding the Athena datasource in QuickSight UI I can see the workgroups, I can validate the connection. Later on I can see the catalog name but I cannot see the databases and tables.  It's just an empty list with a comment:
No tables found
Please make another selection
The QuickSight role is able to listDatabases on all resources.
What else could I check? (The QuickSight, Athena and Glue Catalog are all in the same region)


Have you granted access to the catalog? Share full policy.
